# Discrete math - proving big omega concerns about solution

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logarithms, asymptotics

This is pretty much a duplicate to my last question which I apologize for but I have another concern about my question and I have a quiz in 2 hours so I'm trying to clear my confusion before that.

Determine whether or not the following is true.

$$5n + 3n \log(n) =Ω(n) $$

I'm a little confused on how to prove this question given that I'm not very good with logarithms.

Here is my attempt so far:

$$5n + 3n \log(n) ≥ 5n + 3n = 8n, \qquad c = 8; \quad k =1 $$

So I've been told from multiple people that the equation is true, but 
I'm a little confused because 5n+3nlog(n) given that n = 1 is 5. And the right side of the equation 8n would be equal to 8. So assuming I did everything right, wouldn't it be false because cn is bigger than the function?

Comment: That inequality doesn't need to be true for all $n$, just for all $n\ge n_0$. In your case you want $\log(n)\ge 1$, which is true starting with $n_0=3$ (but not for $n=1,2$, as you correctly noticed)

Comment: but then shouldn't it be n ≥ 3 instead?

Comment: and k would be 3 too then?

Comment: Probably yes to your last question except I cannot be sure because you have never told us what $k$ is supposed to mean.

Comment: last question—am I supposed to use 5n+3nlog(n) to compare to 8n or just 5n+3n? Because with the original function, I realized 3 would also make it less than 8n. It only works with 5n+3n

Comment: I assumed that $\log$ is the natural logarithm. If it is base $10$, then, of course, the starting point jumps to $10$. Anyway, if I were you, I would not bother to take $c=8$ and just estimate the function from below by $5n$ instead, which works for all $n\ge 1$.